Why does my Assembly program continue to execute after reaching the value 10, even with the correct comparison?
I am writing a program in Assembly x86-64 where the goal is to increment a value (num) until it reaches 10. However, despite using the correct comparison to check if num is less than 10, the program continues executing and printing values after 10:
[BITS 64]
default rel

section .data
extern ExitProcess, printf
    msg db "%d", 10, 0
    num dq 0

section .text
    global main

main:
    sub rsp, 56
again:
    mov r8, [num]
    add r8, 1
    mov [num], r8

    lea rcx, [msg]
    mov rdx, [num]
    call printf

    cmp r8, 10
    jge end

    jmp again

end:

    xor rax, rax
    call ExitProcess

Doing this prints:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10 ; <--- ??? don´t stop
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
[...]

But it should stop when it reaches 10. Why is this happening?

Check whether in your ABI r8 is call-preserved across calling printf

Debugging is an important skill, especially with assembly language.  An approach is to single step and double check what the computer does and what you think it should do at each line, just like you would when debugging C or Java.  You should be able to observe what value is in r8 at that cmp r8,10, and this would be a great clue as to what's going wrong.  When you discover the wrong value there, you would look backward in the execution stream (e.g. by restarting the debugger) to see when/where this register was clobbered, and you should be able to discover that the call is the culprit.

Yes yes, I will debug more often, these weeks I was doing a lot of nonsense with the main assembly with simple things like this. Thanks again

Function calls with register-based calling conventions are one of the hardest things in assembly — lots of things that can go wrong, more so that most any other single lines in assembly.  So, take heart!

The register r8 is overwritten ("clobbered") inside the function printf.  You need to reload it from memory before your cmp instruction.  Alternatively you could rearrange your code so the cmp is done together with the code to do the increment.

Your comment opened my mind, I realized that I did the silliest thing in the history of programming Lmao

RBX, RBP, and R12-R15 are call-preserved (and RSI + RDI in Windows x64); any of those could be used for loop counters without needing to use stack memory.  Oh, but the code is already using memory for num, which is weird for a loop variable that doesn't need its address taken.  (@Cabralito).  You also don't need it to be 64-bit; you're only telling printf to print the low 32 bits of it with %d, so might as well save machine-code bytes and use 32-bit operand-size, e.g. with ebx.  Or if you want to keep using memory, load it into edx where you want it anyway as an arg.
